# Make a asp.net mail App in C# with Gmail

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, web

I have tried many times to make an email app using gmail.
I am truly desperate, I have visited the entire Internet even in other languages but I found nothing.

How can I make a email web app in Asp.net c# using gmail?

This is the last code I applied.

```
try
{
    MailMessage ms = new MailMessage();
    ms.From = new MailAddress("myemail@gmail.com");
    ms.To.Add("fillocj@hotmail.it");
    ms.Body = txtTexto.Text;
    ms.IsBodyHtml = true;

    SmtpClient sm = new SmtpClient();
    sm.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

    NetworkCredential nt = new NetworkCredential();

    nt.UserName = "myemail@gmail.com";
    nt.Password = "myPassword";

    sm.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    sm.Credentials = nt;

    sm.Port = 465;

    sm.EnableSsl = true;
    sm.Send(ms);
    LabelError.Text = "Sent";
}
catch
{
    LabelError.Text = "Error";
}
```

I always fail over and over again.
I tried with port: 25, also with 465 and 587. But any of them works fine. I do not know what the problem is. 
Please help with this issue.

Comment: at a quick glance, you probably shouldn't be using `sm.UseDefaultCredentials = true;` since you're assigning it credentials explicitly.  I believe this overrides the credentials you pass to it...

Comment: A second thought occurred to me as well, that is to double check and make sure the ports are actually open on the router.  By default these normally aren't.

Comment: I've also seen some antivirus programs block untrusted code trying to send emails, even if the firewall & router would let them through.

Comment: I see, but what happens when it's in azure.websites?... the app runs fine in VS2012 but it doesn't when it's in "internet"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also might have to configure your gmail account to allow "less secure apps".

See here: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

I had the same issues using an ASP.NET program to send e-mail via Gmail and it did not work until I did this.

Comment: it worked temporally. When I upload my site to azure websites, the site does not send the message! It failed...

Answer (score 0):

This works on my computer using my email and login credentials for that email. If this doesn't work on yours, it is possible that it is a networking issue as indicated in the comment above.

```
        MailMessage mM = new MailMessage();
        mM.From = new MailAddress("myemail@gmail.com");
        mM.To.Add("youremail@gmail.com");
        mM.Subject = "your subject line will go here";
        mM.Body = "Body of the email";
        mM.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient sC = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com") {Port = 587, Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "password"), EnableSsl = true};
        sC.Send(mM);
```

Comment: It worked fine in localhost but it did not in azure!!! any idea why this happens??

Answer (score 0):

Download Google.Apis.Gmail.v1 in nuget.
Create a project in https://console.developers.google.com/.
Inside your project navigate to `Apis & auth > Apis` (enable gmail api)
Navigate to `Apis & auth > Credentials` (create new client id)
Then copy your client id and client secret.

Here's the code in sending email using Gmail Api.

```
public class Gmail
{
public Gmail(ClientSecrets secrets, string appName)
        {
            applicationName = appName;
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(secrets,
                    new[] { GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom, GmailService.Scope.GmailCompose, GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly },
                    "user", CancellationToken.None).Result; 

            service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = applicationName,
            });
        }

public void SendEmail(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail)
        {
            var mimeMessage = MimeKit.MimeMessage.CreateFromMailMessage(mail);
            Message msg = new Message()
            {
                Raw = Base64UrlEncode(mimeMessage.ToString())
            };

            SendMessage(service, msg);
        }

        private Message SendMessage(GmailService service, Message msg)
        {
            try 
            {
                return service.Users.Messages.Send(msg, userid).Execute();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        private string Base64UrlEncode(string input)
        {
            var inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
            // Special "url-safe" base64 encode.
            return Convert.ToBase64String(inputBytes)
              .Replace('+', '-')
              .Replace('/', '_')
              .Replace("=", "");
        }
}
```

UPDATE:

In your controller:

```
public ActionResult SendEmail()
{
 MailMessage msg = new MailMessage()
            {
                Subject = "Your Subject",
                Body = "<html><body><table border='1'><tr>Hello, World, from Gmail API!<td></td></tr></table></html></body>",
                From = new MailAddress("from@email.com")
            };
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("to@email.com"));
            msg.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress("to@email.com")); // important! if no ReplyTo email will bounce back to the sender.

Gmail gmail = new Gmail(new ClientSecrets() { ClientId = "client_id", ClientSecret = "client_secret" }, "your project name");
gmail.SendEmail(msg);
}
```

Comment: I don't tried it yet. But better to use Gmail Api than the older version using SmtpClient.

Comment: I also tried SmtpClient before but I end up reading Gmail Api and implement it.

Comment: Could you show me a sample! I've never used this before. Please! And thanks!